# How to make collection operators respect the controller's sort descriptor?

Tags: objective-c, collections, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

Cocoa has this concept of [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW6) that allow to return a set of objects based on a property. In my array controller I have a number of objects that are executed on a specific date and I want to process them in some way. So I retrieve a list of unique execution dates with this code:

```
NSArray *assignments = categoryAssignments.arrangedObjects;
NSArray* distinctDates = [assignments valueForKeyPath: @"@distinctUnionOfObjects.dayOfExecution"];
```

However, the order in that array does not follow the order in the arrangedObjects array (the dates are sorted descending, while the distinctDates array is sorted ascending).

Is there a way to make the collection operator respect the array controller's sort descriptor?

Comment: Note that valueForKeyPath operates on the **sorted** assignments array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@distinctUnionOfObjects` has to work with arbitrarily (unsorted) input data.
The input data might even (as @Kevin correctly commented) contain objects that
are not comparable at all.
It *could be* that `@distinctUnionOfObjects` uses a `NSMutableSet` internally to find a list
of unique objects (and the objects in a set do not have a defined order). But that
is pure speculation and does not help.

It is simply not documented that the output of `@distinctUnionOfObjects` preserves any order of the input data, and I do not know any parameter to enforce that.

Therefore you have to sort the returned list according to your requirements.

Alternatively, you could replace `valueForKeyPath:...` by the following code 
which preserves the order of the elements. The code uses a `NSMutableSet` to keep track
of all elements added to the result array so far, because testing for membership
is faster with sets as with arrays.

```
NSArray *assignments = categoryAssignments.arrangedObjects;

NSMutableSet *found = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray *distinctDates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *obj in objects) {
    NSDate *date = obj[@"dayOfExecution"];
    if (![found containsObject:date]) {
        [distinctDates addObject:date];
        [found addObject:date];
    }
}
```

Comment: The original data is sorted, so I'd expect it to keep that order. I don't expect it to sort at all. Just keep the original order is what I want.

Comment: @MikeLischke: `@distinctUnionOfObjects` does not promise anything like this. I *assume* that it sorts the elements because that is more effective. Perhaps it uses a `NSSet` internally (which also has no defined order). I do not see a solution using the collection operators (perhaps someone else finds one). You can sort the returned list, or implement your own "uniquing" algorithm.

Comment: I seriously doubt it sorts the array, it's almost definitely a set. Actually, it *can't* sort the array, arbitrary objects are not necessarily orderable.

Comment: @Kevin: The code should create a (mutable) array `distinctDates`, and uses the set `found` to keep track of duplicates (`containsObject` is faster for sets than for arrays). - Or did I make some stupid error?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, yours does. I'm saying, in reference to your statement "It could be that this method sorts the values first to find a list of unique objects" can't sort the values, as they don't necessarily have an order. And it's highly inefficient compared to just using a set.

Comment: Also, better to use [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `[[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:assignments] array]` ought to do it.

Comment: @Kevin: OK, now I see what you mean. My main point was that you cannot expect any order from `@distinctUnionOfObjects`, but you are right that the first sentence does not make much sense, and I will try to fix it. - In my alternative code, I don't see yet how a ordered set would improve something.

Comment: Ok, I see, the collection operator probably uses an intermediate structure (maybe a set) and hence may change the order. Seems I have to live with that. Currently I simple sort the entries explicitely (`distinctDates = [distinctDates sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compareReversed:)];`).